# How to remove the letter (A) in the appendix in overleaf?

Tags: koma-script, appendix

I am trying to remove the letter A from the appendix. How can I have the appendix word alone?[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: please show code as text not as an image, also note this is unrelated to overleaf, scrbook would act the same way in any tex system.

Comment: you have `\chapter{\appendixname}`  if you used  `\chapter*{\appendixname}`  it would be unnumbered, so no **A**

Comment: As David already wrote please post code as text, not as screenshot. But since you are using a KoMa class you coud use `\addchap` instead if `\chapter*`. In this way the headlines and the ToC are taken care of.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great! it worked as I want, but the appendix dissapeared from the table of contents. When I used \addchap instead of \chapter* as campa suggested it worked perfectly.

Comment: @campa it worked and keep it the appendix appearing in the table of contents. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only have an appendix chapter without other numbered element you can use simply

```
\addchap{\appendixname}
```

However, if you have also sections, equations, ... you need to set up a chapter "number":

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,openany]{scrbook} % a5 and openany only for screenshot

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{bar}
\section{baz}

\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{A}
\addchap{\appendixname}
\section{bla}
\section{blabla}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]